# Coding from dbeaver to python sql scripting

Tags: python, sql, dbeaver

I have a database called edgar_transposed. I can work with this data in dbeaver Just realized I could work with this in python. I was hoping to get some help. Can someone help turn this script I used in dbeaver into a sql script I could use in python? I still very new, so hoping this conversion, I could study.

dbeaver code

```
CREATE VIEW reference_table AS
SELECT b.short_name AS 'Table_Name',  
       a.company_name AS  'Company_Name' ,
       a.filing_number AS  'Filing_Number', 
       a.filing_date AS 'Filing_Date',
       a.cik  AS  'Company_CIK' , 
       a.filing_type AS  'Filing_Type',
       a.table_name AS 'Full_Table_Name',  
       b.report_url AS 'Link_to_Table'
FROM (
    SELECT a.filing_number, a.filing_date, a.company_name, a.cik, a.filing_type, b.table_name
    FROM filing_list AS a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT name AS table_name
                FROM sqlite_master
                WHERE type='table') AS b
    ON b.table_name LIKE '%' || a.filing_number || '%') AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN individual_report_links AS b
ON (a.table_name LIKE '%' || REPLACE(b.short_name, ' ' , '_') || '_'||  b.filing_number|| '%')
AND a.filing_number = b.filing_number
GROUP BY a.table_name
ORDER BY a.filing_date
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html